# Center text element in tabview

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, watchos

As I'm learning SwiftUI in the context of building a WatchOS application, I'm trying to achieve something that seems easy but haven't figured out yet.

Looking at this screenshot I would like to have the text label ("Page 2") being displayed in the **vertical center** of the tabview's page instead of the bottom.

[image]

This is the code for my main content view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PageView()
            Divider()
            Text("First steps are hard")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I implemented the page view:

```swift
struct PageView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("Page 1")
                .tag(0)
                .background(Color.yellow)
            Text("Page 2")
                .tag(1)
                .background(Color.red)
            Text("Page 3")
                .tag(2)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        .border(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

I've tried setting different alignment options on the `VStack` as well as setting padding and frames modifier directly on the label. I've also tried embedding `PageView` in another `VStack` but nothing really helped so far.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `GeometryReader` to measure the area only inside the individual tab View you can cut its `.frame` width and height in half. I extracted out your `Text("Page 2")` to demonstrate.

```
struct PageView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("Page 1")
                .tag(0)
                .background(Color.yellow)
            PageTwo()
                .tag(1)
            Text("Page 3")
                .tag(2)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        .border(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct PageTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            Text("Page 2")
                .background(Color.red)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height / 2)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! That seems to work. I didn't know about `GeometryReader` but seems to be quite an important object for frame layouts. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. And I see I misspoke in my answer by saying you can "cut the width" in half when I didn't actually do that. In this case `.frame` is only reading the width value itself but taking half the height. `GeometryReader` can get a little unwieldy but it's very powerful for fine-tuning layout when you need it.